# Need a short explanation on recursion

Tags: recursion

i have a quick question on a recursion in Java. This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println(f(g(n)));
}

public static int f(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return 1;
    else return f(x / 2) + g(x - 1);
    }
public static int g(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return 2;
    else return g(x / 2) + f(x - 1);
}
```

For example: the functional value of f(g(1)) is 9, the functional value of f(g(2)) is 30.
Now, I am new to recursion and I understand how "simple" recursion work with one function but I don't understand how f(g(1)) equals 9. Could someone give me a quick walkthrough for me to understand? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: To generate a walkthrough, paste this code into your IDE, and step through it line-by-line in Debug mode.  Alternatively, run it with paper and pencil.

Comment: By the way: There is nothing mystical about recursion here! `g(x)` works always the same, no matter if called from `g` or from somehwere else. So what you do not understand here is how methods or arithmetic or control flow work.

Comment: Ingo, you are right, my calculation was wrong the whole time, which is why the result was obscure to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, g(1) is executed.

```
g(1) => return g(1/2)+f(1-1) = return g(0) + f(0)
```

g(0) = 2, f(0) = 1

g(1) returns 3

so, f(3) is executed now.

```
f(3) => return f(3/2) + g(2) = return f(1) + g(2)

f(1) = return f(0) + g(0) = 3

g(2) = return g(1) + f(1), which we know to be 3 + 3.
```

So, g(2) = 6,f(1) = 3. Thus, f(3) = 9

hope this helps

Comment: It did! I did the calculation wrong the whole time which is why I always had everything else but 9. Thanks alot!